# Get the value from a div using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the value from a div using `HtmlAgilityPack`.
My `htmlcode` is like this : 
[image]

I need to get the value in `news_content_container` div class as you ca see that in picture is selected so i use this code :

```
     var response1 = await http.GetByteArrayAsync("http://www.nsfund.ir/news?"+link);
                String source1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response1, 0, response1.Length - 1);
                source1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source1);
                HtmlDocument resultat1 = new HtmlDocument();
                resultat1.LoadHtml(source1);
               var val = resultat1.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
  (x => (x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("news_content_container"))).ToList().First().InnerText;;
```

But the result is empty .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var response1 = await http.GetByteArrayAsync("http://www.nsfund.ir/news?"+link);
                String source1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response1, 0, response1.Length - 1);
                source1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source1);
                HtmlDocument resultat1 = new HtmlDocument();
                resultat1.LoadHtml(source1);
               var val = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='news_content_container']").InnerText;
```

Comment: I get this error on the last line :Value cannot be null.

Comment: i got this error dear friend:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: As per my assumption div element is not available with 'news_content_container' class in DOM.This is working for me.

Comment: so what should i do ?!!

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Please, post your "link" variable's value.

Comment: @feeeper what you mean post the link ?

Comment: @feeeper here is the link :http://www.nsfund.ir/news?p_p_id=56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh&_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_mode=news&_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_newsId=3135919&p_p_state=maximized

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Ok, I run that sample code and it works for me fine. Does source1 string contains div with class "news_content_container" in your case?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Can you post source1 content somewhere?